# jQuery fade effects in IE(8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, fade

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
span {display:none;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("span").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Fade in</button>
<span>This is some text.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work in IE8 and probably older versions. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because the span tag is an inline element, it has no layout, unlike block level elements like DIVs.

Swap it to a div and it works, alternatively, this approach (assign block layout to your span, then hide with Jquery) will retain your markup as is and function as desired under IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>

span {display:block;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span").hide();
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("span").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Fade in</button>
<span>This is some text.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you need to retain your text display inline, change your CSS for the span to 'display:inline-block', the following code shows this working with text before and after:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>

span {display:inline-block;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span").hide();
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("span").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Fade in</button>
Previous text <span>This is some text.</span> Following text.
</body>
</html>
```